# How to handle message IF ELSE if it too long

Tags: angular, typescript, if-statement

I've no idea how to figure out the best method to handle this message to display if it too long. I've try to put `IF ELSE` in another page but I don't know how to call it. Example code like bellow:-

**ts file**

```
private getQuotCollection(id: number) {

    this._spin.show();
    this._user.getApi(this.quotCollectionURL + id).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this._spin.hide();
        if (res.status.code === 0) {

          this.respCode = this.quoteCollection?.respCode;

          if (this.respCode == 'v001') {
            this.respDesc = this.translate.instant('code_001');
          }else if (this.respCode == 'v002') {
            this.respDesc = this.translate.instant('code_002');
          }else if (this.respCode == 'v003') {
            this.respDesc = this.translate.instant('code_003');
          }else if (this.respCode == 'v004') {
            this.respDesc = this.translate.instant('code_004');
          }else if (this.respCode == 'v005') {
            this.respDesc = this.translate.instant('code_005');
          }else if (this.respCode == 'v006') {
            this.respDesc = this.translate.instant('code_006');
          }else if (this.respCode == 'v007') {
            this.respDesc = this.translate.instant('code_007');
          }else if (this.respCode == 'v008') {
            this.respDesc = this.translate.instant('code_008');
          }else if (this.respCode == 'v009') {
            this.respDesc = this.translate.instant('code_009');
          }else if (this.respCode == 'v010') {
            this.respDesc = this.translate.instant('code_010');
          } and so on till 'v200'{
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regular expression can check if the `respCode` matches `v###`, extract the numbers, then call `.instant` with those numbers.

```
if (res.status.code !== 0) return;
this.respCode = this.quoteCollection?.respCode;
const match = this.respCode.match(/^v(\d{3})$/);
if (!match) return;
const digits = match[1];
this.respDesc = this.translate.instant('code_' + digits.padStart(3, '0'));
```

Comment: ok thanks for the answer.., I will try first

Answer (score 0):

My first question is, what you really want to achieve. "Less lines of code" may be the goal, but its not the reason. A reason would be "I want to write less code", "I want to write less duplicate code", "I want to make my linter happy"

If you just want to write less code, the mapping is that easy ( "vXXX" => "code_XXX"), and its very likely that it will stay like that, then i would also use a programmatic approach like @CertainPerformance put it in his answer. And you could skip reading the rest of this text :-)

In my experience, quit a lot of developers tell me in similar circumstances that their reason it, that "the linter/sonarqube says the file is to long, therefore i have to shorten it".

But why is this "may not be to long" rule in place? The main reason is, that big files (a lot of code) quite easily become very complex, tangled and hard to understand.

With that in mind, a simple "mapper" like you describe it, may be very long, but its very easy to understand and is far from beeing complex.
The question would be then if the alternatives are better.

Alternatives / Improvements:
You could use "switch". Its still a lot to write, but a lot less then with if/else.

```
switch(this.respCode){
  case "v001": this.respDesc = this.translate.instant('code_001');
  case "v002": this.respDesc = this.translate.instant('code_002');
  ...
  default:  // Throw error because of undefined input
}
```

You could even reduce the amout you have to write, by extracting the value assignement in a small method

```
private assignTranslation(input:string):void{
  this.respDesc = this.translate.instant(input)
}
...

switch(this.respCode){
  case "v001": this.assignTranslation('code_001');
  case "v002": this.assignTranslation('code_002');
  ...
  default:  // Throw error because of undefined input
}
```

But its debatable if this indirection really improves the readability.

You could also try to split the code. For example (if the input has always the same structure), by extracting the number, and then create ranges (0-50 are handled here, 51-100 there, ...). But i would only use that approach when the ranges also have a business meaning. Personally i thinkg, that pure technical spliting in such a case kind of hides the business meaning and therefore should be avoided.

warm regards and happy coding